# xslt removing ending punctuation

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I'm writing an xslt stylesheet to convert MARC-xml records into FGDC-xml metadata. A lot of the MARC fields have extraneous punctuation at the end (periods, colons, commas, etc.) which I would like to strip out. I don't want to remove *all* punctuation from the lines, though. My thought is to write a template with an *if* statement and test if the field ends with a specified character, then remove it, but I'm not sure: 1) if this a good approach, and 2) how to specify that process.

**Edited** My xslt:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0" xmlns:marc="http://www.loc.gov/MARC21/slim" >
<xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:for-each select="marc:collection/marc:record">
  <xsl:result-document method="xml" href="banana_{marc:controlfield[@tag=001]}.xml">
    <metadata>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="self::marc:record"/>
    </metadata>
  </xsl:result-document>
</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="marc:record">
  <pubinfo>
    <pubplace><xsl:value-of select="marc:datafield[@tag=260]/marc:subfield[@code='a']"/></pubplace>
    <publish><xsl:value-of select="marc:datafield[@tag=260]/marc:subfield[@code='b']" /></publish>
  </pubinfo>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And here is my xml document (or at least a representative part of it):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<marc:collection xmlns:marc="http://www.loc.gov/MARC21/slim" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.loc.gov/MARC21/slim http://www.loc.gov/standards/marcxml/schema/MARC21slim.xsd">
<marc:record>
    <marc:leader>01502cfm a2200313 a 4500</marc:leader>
    <marc:controlfield tag="001">7943586</marc:controlfield>
    <marc:datafield tag="260" ind1=" " ind2=" ">
        <marc:subfield code="a">[S.l. :</marc:subfield>
        <marc:subfield code="b">s.n. ,</marc:subfield>
        <marc:subfield code="c">18--]</marc:subfield>
    </marc:datafield>
</marc:record>
<marc:record>
    <marc:leader>01290cem a2200313 a 4500</marc:leader>
    <marc:controlfield tag="001">8108664</marc:controlfield>
    <marc:datafield tag="260" ind1=" " ind2=" ">
        <marc:subfield code="a">Torino :</marc:subfield>
        <marc:subfield code="b">Editore Gio. Batt. Maggi ,</marc:subfield>
        <marc:subfield code="c">1863.</marc:subfield>
    </marc:datafield>
</marc:record>
</marc:collection>
```

Comment: 'not sure what goes here??' Would `substring(1, string-length(marc:datafield[@tag=260]/marc:subfield[@code='b']) - 1)` work?

Comment: I will try that... but first I think I have an error in the syntax of my test statement, though, which is preventing the stylesheet from being compiled correctly. I get the error: "Unexpected colon at start of token"

Comment: Okay, I think I figured out the "unexpected colon..." error, I now have: `<xsl:if test="ends-with(marc:datafield[@tag=260]/marc:subfield[@code='b'],'.|:|,')">`. Forgive me if this is a stupid question @Pawel but should I be enclosing the line you suggested in something? I tried inserting it as is and it returned only an empty tag.

Comment: I thought it was a typo (and I did not know you could use xslt 2.0). Anyways looks like the answer below is what you were looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ends-with()` accepts a simple string, not a regex. That is why you are having problems with:

```
ends-with(marc:datafield[@tag=260]/marc:subfield[@code='b'],'.|:|,')
```

If you want to use regex, then use `matches()`:

```
marc:datafield[@tag=260]/marc:subfield[@code='b']/matches(.,'^.*[\.:,]$')
```

And to remove use `replace()`:

```
replace('Ends with punctuation.', '^(.*)[\.:,]$', '$1')
=>
Ends with punctuation
```

It would also probably be simpler to just execute the replacement on every node instead of testing with the if first, since the no-match case won't do a replacement, which seems like the behavior you want anyway.

Answer (score 2):

**A generic solution exists, which doesn't need to know in advance what are all ending punctuation characters**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"   xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="text()[matches(., '^.*\p{P}$')]">
  <xsl:sequence select="replace(., '(^.*)\p{P}$', '$1')"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on this XML document**:

```
<x>
    <t>Some text .</t>
    <t>Some text2 ;</t>
    <t>Some text3 (</t>
    <t>Some text4 !</t>
    <t>Some text5 "</t>
</x>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced:**

```
<x>
      <t>Some text </t>
      <t>Some text2 </t>
      <t>Some text3 </t>
      <t>Some text4 </t>
      <t>Some text5 </t>
</x>
```

**Explanation**:

Proper use of the **[`p{P}`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#charcter-classes)** character class/category.

`\p` is the escape for the *punctuation* category. `P`is the *all punctuation* property.

**Update**:

The OP has provided specific source XML document and her transformation code.

**Here is her code, modified with the above solution**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0" xmlns:marc="http://www.loc.gov/MARC21/slim" >
<xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:for-each select="marc:collection/marc:record">
  <xsl:result-document method="xml" href="banana_{marc:controlfield[@tag=001]}.xml">
    <metadata>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="self::marc:record"/>
    </metadata>
  </xsl:result-document>
</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="marc:record">
  <pubinfo>
    <xsl:variable name="vSub1" select="marc:datafield[@tag=260]/marc:subfield[@code='a']"/>
    <xsl:variable name="vSub2" select="marc:datafield[@tag=260]/marc:subfield[@code='b']"/>
    <pubplace><xsl:value-of select="replace($vSub1, '(^.*)\s\p{P}$', '$1')"/></pubplace>
    <publish><xsl:value-of select="replace($vSub2, '(^.*)\s\p{P}$', '$1')" /></publish>
  </pubinfo>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank you for the additional answer. I think I understand the logic, but I'm having trouble implementing it properly. I have some other templates that specify output like so: `<publish><xsl:value-of select="marc:datafield[@tag=260]/marc:subfield[@code='b']" /></publish>`  Could that be impacting how the other template expresses? I also wonder if there's a way to eliminate the trailing whitespace at the same time as the ending punctuation.

Comment: @SusanPowell, One shouldn't be guessing what your exact code or XML document is -- you are welcome to edit the question and provide more representable code+data. As for eliminating the trailing whitespace, just use: `'^.*\s\p{P}$'` instead of `'^.*\p{P}$'`

Comment: Sorry about that, I'm new here and forgot that I could edit my original post :$  It is now updated with fuller code. Thank you also for the answer about removing trailing whitespace.

Comment: @SusanPowell, I have modified your code and now it works for any ending punctuation, without the need to have prior knowledge of the possible punctuation characters or the need to modify the code each time a new punctuation character appears in the data. See my updated answer.